# How do I fetch all mongo data which is created greater than a particular date?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I read the $gt attribute has to be used. Not able to get around this. Let's say I have some mongo data like this:

```
{
    "startTime" : "Sun 25 Jan 2015 07:14:26 GMT",
    "endTime" : "",
    "jobStatus" : "JOBCANCELLED",
    "uiState" : "HISTORY",
    "priority" : "SILVER"
}
```

That's how my start time is saved in my Mongo. If I want to get the statuses of all jobs which have the start time greater than today, How do I do it?

```
db.getCollection('jobsCollection').find({"startTime":{$gt: "What here?"})
```

Comment: Try something like this: `db.getCollection('jobsCollection').find({"startTime":{$gt: new Date("2015-01-01")});`.

Comment: You must convert your startTime field from a string to an ISODate object for the date query operators to work. Search [so] for mongo and date and you will find numerous questions about the same problem

Comment: @Martin Is there any way I can convert startTime field to an ISODate temporarily and query so that I don't alter my mongo? In other words, I want to do it without the `save` as the user has answered.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert your startTime from String format to date time format.

To do from mongo shell :

```
 db.jobsCollection.find().forEach(function(doc){doc.startTime = new Date(doc.startTime);db.jobsCollection.save(doc)});
```

And then you can write the query for greater than date :

```
db.jobsCollection.find({"startTime":{$gt: new Date("2014-02-10")});
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: This alters the database, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it will. And there is no point storing the date data as string in MongoDB.

Comment: Yes, storing date as string and not as date object doesn't make sense. Thank you for your suggestion. Marking this answer correct!

Comment: My mongo is huge. As date is already stored as string, the first line takes tremendous time to convert from string to ISODate. I ll leave the answer not marked as correct, as I need to figure out a way of doing it without altering the database.

Comment: @abhidoeslinux : There are two ways you can solve this problem       1. Make it date field from string for which it will take some time and then run the greater than query.Since it is date time format then it can easily compare it with other date time format data and so query time will be small.     2. Keep it as it is string and write complex query which will take more time since no direct comparision of data is present.

Comment: What is wrong with this? db.getCollection('jobsCollection').find({"startTime":{$regex: ".*somedate*}) Looks like it works

Comment: @abhidoeslinux : It will work for the specified date only unless you write a complex regex and test all it cases which can solve the problem. And a famous quote "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems." - [Source](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91818/discussion-between-imagin-and-abhidoeslinux).