# How do I convert python time.gmtime() to MongoDB Date

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to convert the time returned by gmtime() to a readable string. As a mistake, I populated huge data in mongo and stored date as a string. After the discussion in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015162/how-do-i-fetch-all-mongo-data-which-is-created-greater-than-a-particular-date/33015994?noredirect=1#comment53886215_33015994) I am just doing a regex match to get the relevant data from mongo. The problem now is to convert gmtime which is say:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=9, tm_min=49, tm_sec=31, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=282, tm_isdst=0)
```

to this:

```
Tue 27 Jan 2015
```

This is the string format that is stored in mongo

```
{
    "startTime" : "Sun 25 Jan 2015 07:14:26 GMT",
    "endTime" : "",
    "jobStatus" : "JOBCANCELLED",
    "uiState" : "HISTORY",
    "priority" : "SILVER"
}
```

Dumb way to make Mongo query work:

```
db.getCollection('jobsCollection').find({"startTime":{$regex: "Tue 27 Jan 2015.*"}})
```

I need to convert the gmtime to the regex attribute shown in the mongo query

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: I think you are making another mistake. Instead of splitting the string via a regex, you should look at "parsing it" into a contructor for a BSON `Date` object instead. You're also probably better off just running a quick operation in the MongoDB shell which is surely going to be shorter to code. If you're not sure then at least show the "string format" currently stored within your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
print time.gmtime(123456)
print time.strftime("%A %d-%b-%Y", time.gmtime(time.time()))
>>>Friday 09-Oct-2015
```

Answer (score 0):

strftime function should do the trick for you.

Comment: A complete answer should at least contain an example and some more explanation. Otherwise is is just a comment...

Answer (score 0):

You asked the wrong question and hence got the wrong answers. What you really want to do is convert your current string into a BSON `Date`.

Yep just do it in the shell as it's a lot more simple to write that way, and it's a "one off" process, so why write a longer program?:

```js
var bulk = db.jobsCollection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.jobsCollection.find({ "startTime": { "$type": 2 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "startTime": new Date(doc.startTime) }
    });
    count++;

    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.jobsCollection.initializeOrderedBukOp();
    }
});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

And that will convert each string into a BSON `Date` type in the most efficient and safe way possible.